# How to display K means clustering plot in graphWidget of UI using pyqt5?

Tags: python, plot, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

I am developing an UI where I want to display the results of K-Means clustering of a dataset. For that purpose, I am using the plot Widget in pyqtgraph. The code for the same is as follows:

```
    from sklearn.cluster import KMeans 

    clusters = 3

    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = clusters, init = 'k-means++') 
    kmeans.fit(Data4)
    y_means = kmeans.predict(Data4)

    self.plot(Data4[0], Data4[1])

    def plot(self, Sdata1, Sdata2):

    self.graphWidget1.plot(Sdata1, Sdata2, pen=None, symbol='o')
```

So, this thing gives me a scatterplot but without the different color conventions used for different clusters. For illustration, I am getting this

[image: K means result in Pyqt UI]

But I want this to be displayed:

[image: K means result in actual]

Any help in this matter will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

One way is to plot each collection of points separately, e.g.

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import pyqtgraph
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
import numpy as np

class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        nclusters = 3
        self.data = np.random.random((1000,2)) * 10

        kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=nclusters, init='k-means++')
        kmeans.fit(self.data)
        predict = np.array(kmeans.predict(self.data))

        self.graph = pyqtgraph.PlotWidget(self, background='w')
        for i in range(kmeans.n_clusters):
            brush = QtGui.QBrush(pyqtgraph.intColor(i, 3, alpha = 150))
            pen_color = QtGui.QColor(pyqtgraph.intColor(i, 3))
            self.graph.scatterPlot(self.data[predict == i], symbolBrush = brush, pen = pen_color)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.graph)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    window = Widget()
    window.show()
    window.resize(400,400)
    app.exec_()
```

Alternatively, you could plot all points at once but provide an array of pen colors and brushes, e.g.

```
class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        ...

        self.graph = pyqtgraph.PlotWidget(self, background='w')
        colors = [pyqtgraph.intColor(i, 3, alpha=150) for i in self.predict]
        pens = [QtGui.QPen(pyqtgraph.intColor(i, 3), 0) for i in self.predict]
        self.graph.scatterPlot(self.data, pen=pens, symbolBrush=colors)

        ...
```

**Screenshot:**

[image: screenshot of result]